# Code is not working when i am trying to edit the API URL by data entered in form and fetch data from API

Tags: node.js, api, express, ejs, restful-url

Hello everyone as I am beginner in nodejs and expressjs, I am trying to fetch data according to the value entered in the form. And according to the value URL will be edited and send request and get data and show it to page. I wrote the code but it is not working.

Index.ejs

```
    <form action="/index" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Enter json/xml: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name">
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

app.js

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var request = require('request');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    var urlencoderparser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true });

    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
    });

    app.post('/', urlencoderparser, function(req, res){
        res.render('form-data', {data : req.body});
        request.post({
        "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" },
        "url": "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format="+req.body.name,
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            data = JSON.parse(body);
        });
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```

Please help me to find the solution

Comment: Please add more information! Add more info about the issue you're facing. Its not working wouldn't help anybody out :)

Comment: It´s really hard to help you with the info provided but maybe you seem to be posting to "/index" and having express serve on "/" ?

Comment: @AntonioOrtells sir as i am on learning stage, i am not sure of these things. I am just finding the exact way to run code in such type of conditions, I just want to enter the value in the form then according to the form value it will call api URL and fetch data and show on other template file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem with bodyParser.

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Add these just after `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`

And your post function should be like this

```
     app.post('/', function(req, res){
     request('http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format='+req.body.name, function (error, response, body) {
     var data = JSON.parse(body);
     console.log(req.body);
    });
    });
```

And make sure that in the form in your index file you should have `<input type="text" name="name">` 
Because you are using as `req.body.name`

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/index', function(req, res){
        res.render('form-data', {data : req.body});
        request.post({
        "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" },
        "url": "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format="+req.body.name,
        }, (error, response, body) => {
            if(error) {
                return console.log(error);
            }
            data = JSON.parse(body);
        });
        console.log(req.body);
    });
```